# Display loading state and change route when API call is successfull

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

While working on a side project, I faced an issue with `react-router-dom`.

What I want to implement is: *When I submit a Form, I need to save the data on my server. While the request is pending, I need to display a loading indicator. Once the server says everything is ok, I need to redirect the user on a new page*

**action.js**

```
export const addNotification = value => async dispatch => {
   dispatch(addNotificationPending())

   try {
     const response = await client.createNotification(values)

     dispatch(addNotificationSuccess(response))
   } catch(e) {
     dispatch(addNotificationFailure())
   }
}
```

**component.js**

```
class CreateNotificationForm extends Component {
  onSubmit = (values) => {
    this.props.addNotification(parameters, history)
  }

  render() {
    const { isCreating } = this.props
    const submitBtnText = isCreating ? 'Creating...' : 'Submit'

    return (
      <Form>
        // content omitted
        <Submit value={submitBtnText} />
      </Form>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isCreating: getIsFetching(state)
})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({ // omitted })
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CreateNotificationForm)
```

So far so good: When I submit my form, the form's submit button shows a `Creating...` text.

However, how do I tell `react-router` to load a new path once the request is successful?

Right now, I've done that by using `withRouter` and using `this.props.history` as a second argument for `this.props.addNotification`.

It works great, but it seems really wrong

I've seen solutions using `react-router-redux`, but I don't really want to add a new middleware to my store.

Should I make the API call inside my component and use a `Promise`?

Any help?

Comment: Why it seems really wrong ? just curious !!

Comment: Just a feeling, but I might be wrong!

Comment: I updated my answer. TL;DR use a promise, like you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update:*

After working a little on my own React project, and thinking about similar situations where I handle route changes there, I decided I want to change my original answer. I think the callback solution is OK, but the solution that you already mentioned of making the API call inside your component and using a promise is better. I realized that I've actually been doing this in my own app for a while now.

I use redux-form in my app, and it provides onSubmitSuccess/onSubmitFail functions that you can use to handle the submit result, and each of those rely on you returning a promise  (usually from your action creator).

I think the fact that one of the most popular packages for form submission in React/Redux supports this pattern is an indication that it's probably a good pattern to use. Also, since react-router passes history into your component, it seems logical that they expect most people to do a lot of their programmatic route changes inside the component.

Here's an example of what the promise solution would look like with your code:

**action.js**

```js
export const addNotification = value => dispatch => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    dispatch(addNotificationPending())

    try {
     const response = await client.createNotification(values)

     dispatch(addNotificationSuccess(response))
     resolve(response)
    } catch(e) {
     dispatch(addNotificationFailure())
     reject(e)
    }
  })
}
```

**component.js**

```js
onSubmit = async () => {
  try {
    await this.props.addNotification(parameters)
    this.props.history.push('/new/route')
  } catch(e) {
    // could use a try/catch block here to display
    // an error to the user here if addNotification fails,
    // or go to a different route
  }
}
```

*Old Answer:*

A simple solution would be to allow addNotification() to accept a callback function as an optional second argument.

```js
export const addNotification = (value, callback=null) => async dispatch => {
   dispatch(addNotificationPending())

   try {
     const response = await client.createNotification(values)

     dispatch(addNotificationSuccess(response))
     (typeof callback === 'function') && callback()
   } catch(e) {
     dispatch(addNotificationFailure())
   }
}
```

Then inside your component use the router to go to the new route.

```js
onSubmit = (values) => {
  this.props.addNotification(parameters, () => {
    this.props.history.push('/new/route')
  })
}
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to do history.push() within thunk? I haven't used thunk. Just curious to know. As I don't know why wouldn't we easily do it in thunk, rather than passing a callback method. (Ofcourse callback might help to do many other things, but still)

Comment: History is a prop that is made available to every component that is used with react-router. Redux-thunk is middleware for redux that allows you to dispatch more than one action when you are calling an initial action that is asynchronous. So, your thunk isn't really going to know about history.push(). It's just there to dispatch more actions which will return data to your reducers.

Comment: Hmm, in my projects I've used history.push() in my sagas, based on what i receive from the api and that has been working well. Talking about how i can access history in middleware, its a simple import `import {hashHistory} from 'react-router';`

Comment: Oh yeah, you could do that too. So, you could replace my callback with history.push() after importing it. You said "within thunk" but I think of that  code as being within the action. I think of the thunk as what is dispatching those additional actions inside addNotification(). I like the callback approach because it makes it clear inside the component itself that after onSubmit calls addNotification() it's going to change the route. Plus this way addNotification() doesn't always have to change the route. It only does if you supply a callback. It makes the function more re-useable.

Comment: agreed to the point of reusability. thanks for explaining! 

Answer (score 0):

You should not write your asynchronous calls in reducers or actions as the documentation clearly suggests them to be pure functions. You will have to introduce a redux-middleware like `redux-thunk` or `redux-saga` (I personally prefer sagas)

All your async calls will happen inside the middleware, and when it succeeds, you can use react-routers history `.replace()` or `.push()` methods to update your route. Let me know if it makes sense

Comment: It looks like he's already using redux-thunk. He is using it's dispatch function inside of his action.

Comment: My bad, the first code is not a `reducer.js`, but `action.js`....
And I'm already using `redux-thunk`

Answer (score 0):

You can use one popular package axios

See Here https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

and you can implement your login like

```
axios.post('/user', {
firstName: 'Fred',
lastName: 'Flintstone'
})
.then(function (response) {
console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
console.log(error);
});
```

You can write your loader login while calling api

and then you can hide your loader in .then

Comment: `client.createNotification` is using `axios` :)